# ReactJS: How to pass information or communicate from one component to another or how to go on next

Tags: reactjs

I'm still a bit starting up on react and I've now used my 2nd solution ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913387/show-hide-components-in-reactjs?noredirect=1)) to show/hide components.

My problem now is if I have multiple child elements and I need to open another component (Preference) (this I managed already, and clicking outside or other place hides it) but at the same time I need to pass information to that other component. I have attached my small demo of it. My question again is how do I pass from `Child`/`Child2` components say it's `_preferences` or it's coordinates to the `Preferences` component?

**edit**: added jsfiddle link.

the whole code snippet:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.7.0/lodash.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/react-with-addons.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="render-here"></div>

    <script type="text/jsx">
      var Parent = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function () {
          return { 
            showPreference: false,
            childComponents: 0
          };
        },
        shouldComponentUpdate: function() {
          console.log('parent should update');
          return true;
        },
        _click: function() {
          this.setState({childComponents: this.state.childComponents + 1});
        },
        _showPreference: function() {
          this.setState({showPreference: true})
        },
        _hidePreference: function() {
          this.setState({showPreference: false})
        },
        render: function() {
          var childComponents = [];

          _.times(this.state.childComponents, function(n) {
            if (n % 2)
              childComponents.push(<Child key={'foobar'+n} showPreference={this._showPreference} />)
            else
              childComponents.push(<Child2 key={'foobar'+n} showPreference={this._showPreference} />)
          }.bind(this));

          return(
            <div style={{height:'100%', width:'100%', border:'1px solid blue'}} onClick={this._hidePreference}>
              {this.state.showPreference ? <Preference /> : null}
              <div onClick={this._click}>Add components</div>
              {childComponents}
            </div>
          )
        }
      });

      var Preference = React.createClass({
        shouldComponentUpdate: function() {
          console.log('preference should update');
          return true;
        },
        _click: function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
        },
        render: function() {
          return(
            <div ref="pref" style={{position:'absolute', left: '250px'}} onClick={this._click}>
              <div>Some preferences here...</div>
            </div>
          )
        }
      });

      var Child = React.createClass({
        shouldComponentUpdate: function() {
          console.log('child should update');
          return true;
        },
        _preferences: ['child', 'preferences'],
        _click: function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          this.props.showPreference();
        },
        render: function() {
          return(
            <div ref="me" onClick={this._click}>Child - click me for preference</div>
          )
        }
      });

      var Child2 = React.createClass({
        shouldComponentUpdate: function() {
          console.log('child should update');
          return true;
        },
        _preferences: ['child2', 'preferences'],
        _click: function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          this.props.showPreference();
        },
        render: function() {
          return(
            <div ref="me" onClick={this._click}>Child 2 - click me for preference</div>
          )
        }
      });

      React.render(<Parent name="foobar" />, document.getElementById('render-here'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/index/gx49dvnw/).

Answer (score 0):

First off, never store arbitrary objects in your React components, like you do with `_preferences: ['child', 'preferences']`. Any data in a component should be inside the `state` of that component, or be passed as `props` to it.

If you put an array like that on the component object, it will be shared between all instances of that component. If you only ever have one instance of it, you probably won't notice it. But it will probably bite you as soon as you need more than that. And by using `state` and `setState` to mutate it, React knows when to re-render your component.

Now to your question; your `Parent` component should probably be the component that holds the `preferences` object in it's state. The `Parent` component then passes it to the `Child`, `Child2` and `Preference` components as props. If `Child`, `Child2` or `Preference` wants to modify that object, `Parent` would pass a callback as a prop to them, which they can call to tell `Parent` that it should be changed. Something like:

```
let React = require('react');

let Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      preferences: {
        someKey: 'someValue'
      }
    };
  },
  changePreference(pref) {
    this.setState(state => {
      state.preferences[pref.name] = pref.value;
      return state;
    });
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child 
          preferences={this.state.preferences} 
          onChangePreference={pref => this.changePreference(pref)} 
        />
        <Preference 
          preferences={this.state.preferences} 
          onChangePreference={pref => this.changePreference(pref)} 
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi. Still reading your answer, but what are `=>` in javascript? Your syntax is a bit different from mine.

Comment: I've used some upcoming features in Javascript in the code. It's quite common for React projects to use a compiler like Babel to compile ES6 code into ES5 code, which lets you use new features today, without having to wait for browsers to implement them. This: `let func = pref => this.changePreference(pref)` is what's called an arrow function. Its ES5 equivalent is `var that = this; var func = function(pref) { return that.changePreference(pref); }`.