# How to show/hide component on click in React-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component:

```
class CommentBox extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Some comment</p>
                <a>Post a reply to this comment</a>
            </div>
            <ReplyForm />
        )
    }
}
```

I need this `ReplyForm` to be hidden on initial load. How to trigger it's state by clicking on a tag?

Comment: Are you actually using Redux anywhere?

Comment: Few related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24502898/465053) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29913387/465053).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should add some flag to the state of `CommentBox`. And if value of this flag is `false` when don't show `ReaplyFrom` and vice versa. Heres the code and working example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzrzQZ

```
class ReplyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>I'm ReplyForm</div>
    )
  }
}

class CommentBox extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showReply: false
    }
  }
  onClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({showReply: !this.state.showReply})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Some comment</p>
         <a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} href='#'>Post a reply to this comment</a>
        {this.state.showReply && < ReplyForm / >}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You are mutating state inside a component. Is that something ok in Redux? According to it's defination state is maintained and mutated by a global store.

Comment: @AftabNaveed I just tried to show that you don't need Redux or any other extra lib to perform such operation. But I guess you right, if you are using Redux then `showReply` should be placed in store.

Comment: Using this model I am getting a message like "Warning: setState(...): can only update a mounted or mounting component " if I use setState inside one of the components that I am trying to show up or hide. Is there anyway to avoid this problem?

Comment: Isn't using `setState()` defeating the purpose of using Redux/not answering the question? OP asked for a Redux solution so I figured they wanted to manage state accordingly

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
class CommentBox extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showForm: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    const showHide = {
      'display': this.state.showStatus ? 'block' : 'none'
    };

    const showReplyForm = () => {
      this.setState({showForm: true});
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
            <p>Some comment</p>
            <a onClick={showReplyForm}>Post a reply to this comment</a>
        </div>
        <div style={showStatus}>
          <ReplyForm />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This way is stopping me getting messages like -- Warning: setState(...): can only update a mounted or mounting component " --

Answer (score 0):

You can try [rc-if-else](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-if-else) module

```js
npm install --save rc-if-else
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { If } from 'rc-if-else';

class CommentBox extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            showForm: false
        }
    }

    render() {
        const showReplyForm = () => {
            this.setState({showForm: true});
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p>Some comment</p>
                    <a onClick={showReplyForm}>Post a reply to this comment</a>
                </div>
                <If condition={this.state.showStatus}>
                    <ReplyForm />
                </If>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```