# Insert a component when clicked and remove the componet when click other than that component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`ContentWithFooter` has list of `Card`'s. And each `Card` has a menu to flag or delete the Card (article). When the `icon` is clicked, I want to insert the menu (`<DeleteFlagPost/>`) for that Card only and not all the cards. Also after the menu is inserted, when clicked other than that menu, remove it from the menu component. How do I do that? I know this is a long list of HOW, but your help will really help me understand more. Thank you.

ContentWithFooter.js:

```
class ContentWithFooter extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Card/>
                <Card/>
                <Card/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Card.js

```
class Card extends React.Component {
    handleDeleteFlag() {
        return(
            // GET THE CLICKED OBJECT OF THIS CARD AND INSERT <DeleteFlagPost/>???
        );
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <article class="article">
            ...
                <div class="delete-flag-post-btn">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true" onClick={this.handleDeleteFlag}></i>

                    // INSERT THE <DeleteFlagPost/> here when clicked on I element...

                </div>
            ...
            ...
            </article>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Keep active card in the contentwithfooter

 class ContentWithFooter extends React.Component {
    updateMenuForCards(cardNumActive) {
      this.setState({
          cardNumActive
      })
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Card cardNumber= 0 showMenu={cardNumActive === 0} updateMenuForCards={updateMenuForCards}/>
                <Card cardNumber= 1 showMenu={cardNumActive === 0} updateMenuForCards={updateMenuForCards}/>
                <Card cardNumber= 2 showMenu={cardNumActive === 0} updateMenuForCards={updateMenuForCards}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

    class Card extends React.Component {
            constructor() {
               super(props);
            }

            handleDeleteFlag() {
                this.props.updateMenuForCards(this.props.cardNumber)
            }
            renderDeleteFlag() {
                if (this.props.showMenu) {
                    return (<DeleteFlag/>)
                }
            }
            render() {
                return(
                    <article class="article">
                    ...
                        <div class="delete-flag-post-btn">
                            <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true" onClick={this.handleDeleteFlag}></i>

                            {this.renderDeleteFlag()}

                        </div>
                    ...
                    ...
                    </article>
                );
```

Comment: How to remove the component when clicked other than that component?