# show and hide react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my react JS Code i have 2 Onclick function

```
    class Traders extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: 10,
          listVisibleList: false,
          gridVisibleList: false,
          listVisibleGrid: false,
          gridVisibleGrid: false

        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
      }


      onClickListView() {
        this.setState({
          listVisibleList: !this.state.listVisibleList,
          gridVisibleList: !this.state.gridVisibleList
        });
      }

      onClickGridView(){
        this.setState({
          listVisibleGrid: !this.state.listVisibleGrid,
          gridVisibleGrid: !this.state.gridVisibleGrid
        });
      }

      render() {
        const widthRisk = {
          width: '60%'
        };

        return (
          <div id="home">

                      <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={2}>
                        <div className="option-layout">
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#" onClick={() => this.onClickListView()}>
                                <img src="../../src/assets/images/list.png" className="img-respnsive" alt="list" />
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#" onClick={() => this.onClickGridView()} >
                                <img src="../../src/assets/images/grid.png" className="img-respnsive" alt="grid" />
                              </a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </Col>

                {
                  this.state.listVisibleList ? <ListTrader /> : <ListTrader />
                }



                {/* <ListTrader /> */}
                {/* <GridTrader /> */}

                </div>
)
}
```

The problem is how i want to show some specific component.

When i click `onClickListView` it shows `<ListTrader />` Component and `<GridTrader />` Component hide

When i click `onClickGridView` it shows `<GridTrader />` Component and `<ListTrader />` Component hide

I already tried to do some show and hide referring from this question
[Show/Hide components in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913387/show-hide-components-in-reactjs)

But the onClick from that question the function showing like toggle function. Any idea how to solve this?

Your help really appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand what you want, could you please explain?

Comment: hi @AlexanderTuniev sorry if my grammar hard for u to understand. To summarize it i have 2 onclick function so when i click onClickListView it shows <ListTrader /> Component and <GridTrader /> Component hide

Comment: @AlexanderTuniev i have some question can i ask here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not working example but hope will give you a direction, (if I correctly understand your issue)You can hold in state string variable and based on value it has display what you want.

```
class Traders extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
      ....
      visibleView:'list' //'grid'
     };
  }

  componentDidMount() {}


 onToggleView(view) {
   this.setState({
    visibleView:view
  });
 }

render() {
  const widthRisk = {
    width: '60%'
  };

return (
  <div id="home">
    <div className="app-body" id="view">
      <div className="padding font-responsive">
        <Row>

  ..............
  ...............
              <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={2}>
                <div className="option-layout">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" onClick={() => this.onToggleView('list')}>
                        <img src="../../src/assets/images/list.png" className="img-respnsive" alt="list" />
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" onClick={() => this.onToggleView('grid')} >
                        <img src="../../src/assets/images/grid.png" className="img-respnsive" alt="grid" />
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </Col>
            </div>
          </Col>

        </Row>

        {
          this.state.visibleView ==='list'? <ListTrader /> : <GridTrader />
        }



        {/* <ListTrader /> */}
        {/* <GridTrader /> */}

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```